# Use wget to download pdf with no direct link

Tags: pdf, wget

Some websites provide pdf files for viewing but I can't download such pdf files with wget.
Calling the website in question from my browser views the pdf:
https://www.lokalmatador.de/epaper/ausgabe/gemeinderundschau-muehlhausen-14-2021/

But using the following code I only get a pdf file with 0 lenght.

```
wget --content-disposition -nd https://www.lokalmatador.de/epaper/ausgabe/gemeinderundschau-muehlhausen-14-2021/
```

I tried some combinations with saving and loading cookies and referer but nothing works.
At this point I'm just curious what is happening and why wget is not fetching anything except maybe an empty index.html.

Comment: You meant -nd not --nd ?

Comment: @Anton You are right. Fixed it to -nd, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was looking at server response, it was saying the content length was 0.

```
--2021-04-17 14:59:35--  https://www.lokalmatador.de/epaper/ausgabe/gemeinderundschau-muehlhausen-14-2021/
Resolving www.lokalmatador.de (www.lokalmatador.de)... 37.202.6.70
Connecting to www.lokalmatador.de (www.lokalmatador.de)|37.202.6.70|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Sat, 17 Apr 2021 13:59:36 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=477e8a1d2b3dd74bc5b6b408a6d74edd; expires=Mon, 17-May-2021 13:59:36 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=.lokalmatador.de; httponly; samesite=lax
  Upgrade: h2,h2c
  Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
  Content-Length: Array
  Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
  Expires: Mon, 17 May 2021 13:59:36 GMT
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Content-Type: application/pdf
Length: 0 [application/pdf]
Remote file exists but does not contain any link -- not retrieving.
```

So looked at the manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html

And there is a command just exactly for this:

```
‘--ignore-length’

    Unfortunately, some HTTP servers (CGI programs, to be more precise) send out bogus Content-Length headers, which makes Wget go wild, as it thinks not all the document was retrieved. You can spot this syndrome if Wget retries getting the same document again and again, each time claiming that the (otherwise normal) connection has closed on the very same byte.

    With this option, Wget will ignore the Content-Length header—as if it never existed.
```

Then the wget command started working as expected:

```
 wget --ignore-length -O epaper.pdf https://www.lokalmatador.de/epaper/ausgabe/gemeinderundschau-muehlhausen-14-2021
```

Here is output which I'm seeing with the ignore length:

```
--2021-04-17 14:56:19--  https://www.lokalmatador.de/epaper/ausgabe/gemeinderundschau-muehlhausen-14-2021
Resolving www.lokalmatador.de (www.lokalmatador.de)... 37.202.6.70
Connecting to www.lokalmatador.de (www.lokalmatador.de)|37.202.6.70|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: ignored [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘epaper.pdf’

epaper.pdf                        [                  <=>                             ]   4.39M  1.23MB/s    in 3.6s

2021-04-17 14:56:23 (1.21 MB/s) - ‘epaper.pdf’ saved [4601842]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked up the manual and was aware of the 0 lenght but couldn't put 1 and 1 together. --ignore-length did the trick.